# Why is the definition of the stochastic integral w.r.t. an Ito process consistent?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have the following definition for an

---

**Ito process**:

For $a(\omega, t), b(\omega, t)$ real valued, adapted stochastic processes
that respectively satisfy the conditions
$$
P(\int_0^t \vert a(\omega, s)\vert ds < \infty ) = 1
\quad \text{and} \quad
P(\int_0^t b(\omega, s)^2 ds < \infty ) = 1
$$

and Ito-process has the form
$$
X_t = x_0 + \int_0^t a(\omega, s) ds + \int_0^t b(\omega, s) dB_s.
$$

---

Now for another adapted stochastic process $f(\omega, t)$ that satisfies
$$
P(\int_0^t \vert f(\omega, s) a(\omega, s)\vert ds < \infty ) = 1
\quad \text{and} \quad
P(\int_0^t (f(\omega, s)b(\omega, s))^2 ds < \infty ) = 1
$$

the **stochastic integral of $f$ with respect to $X$** is defined as
$$
\int_0^t f(\omega, s) dX_s := 
\int_0^t f(\omega, s)a(\omega, s) ds + \int_0^t f(\omega, s)b(\omega, s) dB_s
$$

---

For the Ito integral I have seen the interpretation of say the cumulative gains or losses of a gaming/investing strategy $f(\omega,t)$ w.r.t. an underlying asset price (the Brownian motion). It makes sense to me to extend the original definition to more complicated asset price models (here an Ito-process), but I don't see how the above defined stochastic integral is

a) consistent with the formal definition of the Ito integral - i.e. whether this integral can also be derived as a limit of sums of this form
$$
\lim_{\vert \mathcal{P} \vert \to 0}
\sum_{t_i \in \mathcal{P}} f(t_i) (X_{t_i} - X_{t_{i-1}})
$$
b) consistent with the interpretation given above

So essentially I'm asking: why does this definition make sense?

Comment: $f(t_i)$ is not even well defined without further assumptions.

Comment: I believe that the first definition simply comes from the linearity of the stochastic integral in the integrator. The stochastic integral is formally defined to have certain properties, one of which is linearity in both integrand and integrator. 
One can prove the existence of the stochastic integral without appealing to the Riemann-type sum at all.

Comment: @user7924249 If it was an application of linearity you would have $\int_0^t a(\omega, s) dB_s$ but the first integral on the rhs is not an Ito Integral. Well how would you proof that? Would that proof give insight w.r.t. the relation to the Ito integral?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment here.

It does indeed follow from linearity of the stochastic integral. One may also note, that the Itô integral wrt some function/process does not necessarily have to yield an integral wrt a Brownian motion. Your process $X$ does have a drift term, which is a Riemann integral, so naturally such Riemann integrals are likely to appear when integrating wrt $X$.

Heuristically speaking, we can write out what $dX_{s}$ is and obtain
$$
\int_{0}^{t}f(s)dX_{s} = \int_{0}^{t}f(s)\left( a(s)ds+b(s)dB_{s} \right)
$$
Depending on the regularity of your functions $f,a,b$, this stochastic integral may also be obtained by taking limits of Riemann sums as you suggest. However, the Itô integral is not usually defined as the limit of Riemann sums. This type of limit is usually only valid in probability and for nice integrands $f$ (for example left-continuous integrands).

Instead, one may define the Itô integral more abstractly as the unique adapted process satisfying certain "nice" properties, such as linearity and local martingality. This allows for a large class of integrators and integrands, but is naturally less intuitive to think of.

In order to make the above heuristics more formal, I suppose you could start by showing that the Itô integral behaves that way for simple integrands, i.e. where $f$ is of the form
$$
f(\omega , t) = f_{0}(\omega)\mathbb{1}_{\lbrace 0\rbrace}(t) + \sum_{i=1}^{n}f_{i}(\omega)\mathbb{1}_{(t_{i},t_{i+1}]}(t)
$$
For such functions/processes we know exactly how the Itô integral should be defined. Then we may take appropriate limits of these simple functions and extend the class of integrable $f$'s to more interesting functions. In the end, the largest class of integrands will be the class of predictable processes.

Comment: It feels like you miss-understood my question on purpose just to be correct about a point that is not relevant here.

Comment: If you already have a general concept of a stochastic integral then the special version w.r.t. an Ito process follows by linearity. But the above is a definition, not a consequence. Your approach then makes me question: 
What is the definition of this stochastic integral, and what does it calculate?

Abstractly proving something exists only has any benefit if the object in question is useful and has meaning.

Comment: I sincerely do not understand what you are asking then. I suppose the first of your definitions is so defined because it bypasses having to define the Itô integral abstractly. The second definition as the Riemann sums are rarely used as formal definitions. I have only seen that in finance textbooks where this definition is used due to intuition and lack of mathematical rigour. I hope you find an answer to your question somewhere.

Comment: I'm asking for meaning and interpretation mate. To be honest I am surprised by the fact that so many people in my field seem to struggle with the idea that their concepts should have meaning. It is as though holy books of empty theory fell from the sky to inspire people to create more empty theory for the purpose of being busy. When in reality people abstracted meaningful ideas and gave them a rigorous foundation. What is the meaningful idea behind a stochastic integral and how does it extend the meaningful idea behind the Ito integral? That is my question.

Comment: No, your question was literally posed as "why does this definition make sense". When asked about a mathematical object on a forum dedicated to mathematics it should be no surprise that the answers you get are concerned with the abstract side of things. For the record, there are many different stochastic integrals where the Itô integral is only one of these (and the thing you call a "stochastic integral" IS the Itô integral), so your wording in these comments is quite confusing. 
Good luck in your quest for "meaning". I'm out.

Comment: I apologize, this part of your comment
"(and the thing you call a "stochastic integral" IS the Itô integral)"
actually helped my understanding. The thing is that in our class we derived the Itô integral (via simple functions etc) only for $\int dB_t$ and since many of the proofs along the way relied upon the friendly properties of the Brownian motion it seemed out of the blue to me to have integrals like $\int dX_t$ simply defined as above. I.e. I wondered how we know that definition even makes sense and represents what we would expect. Excuse my lack of understanding.

Comment: No worries, we misunderstood each other from the start so that is why I backed out. I am glad that it makes more sense to you now!